# How do I set a monospace font for all new files in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

When editing .markdown files (presumably opened as plain text), Xcode 4.1 uses a non-monospace font. I'd like all files regardless of type to use a monospace font. I didn't see any options to change the default behavior.

Comment: Are you asking to change the font of the editor window?

Comment: No, I want to make any and all files opened use a monospaced font. I'm using the default theme from the "Fonts & Colors" pref tab.

Comment: Use presentation one or you can change the font for each and every one of the category.